# Explain @:remove @:generic metadata combination

Tags: haxe

Consider class with type parameter, that should be used as `Map` key.

```
class Foo<K> {
  var map: Map<K, Dynamic> = new Map();
}
```

This does not compile with error `Type parameters of multi type abstracts must be known`.

The reason is understandable - `Map` is `abstract` and it's underlying type is selected based on key type, so key type should be known when compiling `new Map()` expression. On the other hand non-generic type with type parameters are compiled once for all parameters.

Looks like adding `@:generic` metadata should help. But actually it does not. My guess was that this is because haxe compiler compiles `@:generic` types the same as it does with non-generic types, and only then does some extra work for generic type. So I was thinking that having a `Map` with key type defined by type parameter is impossible in haxe.

But recently I've stumbled upon this issue: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/2537
Simn's answer there says, that this can be done by adding `@:remove @:generic` metadata. And it actually works.

```
@:remove @:generic
class Foo<K> {
  var map: Map<K, Dynamic> = new Map();
}
```

For me this looks like magic and I'm not comfortable with this. In documentation I only see that
*@:remove  Causes an interface to be removed from all implementing classes before generation.* That does not explain why this works.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace Map by haxe.ds.BalancedTree and use only @:generic without @:remove, you will see your class Foo generated on your target containing new BalancedTree< object, object > (object is Dynamic). That means, Foo class holds general BalancedTree< object, object > type, while Foo_String for example holds generic BalancedTree< string, object > type. Now, if you go back to your Map, you will see that "Abstract haxe.ds.Map has no @:to function that accepts haxe.IMap< Foo.K, Dynamic >", e.g. no Map< Dynamic, Dynamic > implementation exists. That's why you need to use @:remove which will actually stop generation of Foo class, or at least, remove new Map< Dynamic, Dynamic > from the Foo (@:remove "Causes an interface to be removed" is misleading here)

Comment: Compiler generates generic implementation only for type parameters that were actually used. What @:remove adds here? Why @:generic is not enough?

Comment: You should ask Haxe team why is like that. For example, non-generic Foo can be used as var f:Foo<Dynamic> = new Foo<String>(), but generic one will fail with cannot cast Foo<String> to Foo<Dynamic>. Probably because it is about performance (speed) about generic vs. non-generic. But you should ask (open an issue) since you "discovered" this, I'm here only explaining what is going on under the hood.